# Does Azure DevOps deployment group target requires an internet connection?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I want to register a target using a registration script generated by Azure DevOps. My production server does not have an active internet connection, will the registration script work?

If not what Url's do I need to specify in the proxy to allow that communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be able to access the URL for your azure-devops account to register an agent.  You can also reference this documentation for [whitelist addresses.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/faq-network-connections?view=vsts)